# Link between norm 2 of a matrix and eigenvalue

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Can anyone tell if the below relationship exists considering that $K$ is the co-variance matrix and $\lambda$ is eigenvalue? Is there any property that is used?

$||K^{-1}||_2= \lambda ^{max}(K^{-1}) = \lambda^{min}(K)^{-1} \leq \sigma^{-2}$

Comment: The covariance matrix is symmetric positive semi-definite, so by asking about $K^{-1}$ I assume its existence and hence that $K$ is positive definite. It follows that $K^{-1}$, too, is positive definite.

$${}$$

That said, what is $\sigma$?